# On coursera what exactly does Andrew Ng say in videos Lectures 60 & 61 of machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, model-selection

[Model Selection and Train/Validation/Test Sets - Stanford University | Coursera:](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/QGKbr/model-selection-and-train-validation-test-sets)

At **10:59**~**11:10**

> One final note: I should say that in the machine learning as of this practice today, there **aren't** many people that will do that early thing that I talked about, and said that, you know...​

Is my comprehension correct?
Because English subtitles on coursera sometimes are not correct.
As I konw, here what Chinese subtitle means is opposite to what English one does.
So I am not sure whether Andrew Ng said "there **aren't**" or "there **are**"

Thanks for your reading.​

---

I would like to ask **another one**.

[Diagnosing Bias vs. Variance - Stanford University | Coursera:](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/yCAup/diagnosing-bias-vs-variance)

At **02:34**~**02:36**, what Andrew Ng said is not quite clear as well as the English subtitle.

My comprehension is as following

> If d equals 1,.... to be high training error.

It's not that complete.

Would anyone like to identify that?

Thank you...

Comment: For the second question, Andrew says: "If d equals 1, we're going to have a relatively high training error". But please, don't change your question, if you have an other question you should ask a new one, see: [how to ask](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @agold, I am sorry.  I hope you and other users can get my apology. I am glad here is a forum and users kind to discuss machine learning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**, he actually says the opposite:

> One final note: I should say that in the machine learning as of this practice today, there **are** many people that will do that early thing that I talked about, and said that, you know...​

Then he says (the "early thing" he talked about):

> selecting your model as a test set and then using the same test set to report the error
>   ...
>   unfortunately many people do that

---

In this lesson he explains about separating the data set:

1. *training set* to train the model;
2. *cross validation set* to find the right parameters;
3. *test set* to find the final generalization error (of the function with the best parameter values found during using the *cross validation set*).

So Andrew Ng is complaining that many people us the same data set to find the right parameters, and then report the error of that data set as final *generalization error*.

Comment: Now I see the English subtitle is incorrect here, Chinese one is correct.